# Call Stored Procedure from c# with date in parameters

Tags: c#, sql, asp.net, sql-server, rdlc

I need to call a stored procedure from C# with 2 dates as parameters. I did this many times, but never with dates, and it does not work, the parameters are not interpreted.

My date is like "2018-01-30"

My C# function :

```
private DataTable getAccidents ( DateTime dateDebut, DateTime dateFin)
{
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ATPConnectionString"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection cn = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("getAccidents", cn);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;

        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_anneeDebut", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateDebut;
        cmd.Parameters.Add("@p_anneeFin", SqlDbType.DateTime).Value = dateFin;

        SqlDataAdapter adp = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
        adp.Fill(dt);
    }

    return dt;
}
```

And my stored procedure in SQL Server looks like this:

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[getAccidents]
    (@p_anneeDebut DATETIME, 
     @p_anneeFin DATETIME)
AS
    SELECT * 
    FROM T_ACCIDENT
    LEFT OUTER JOIN TR_SALARIE AS victime ON T_ACCIDENT.SAL_idVictime = 
victime.SAL_id
    ...
    LEFT OUTER JOIN ERP.dbo.TR_COST_CENTER as cost_center ON cost_center.COS_id = T_ACCIDENT.ACC_lieuPrecis
    WHERE 
        CONVERT(DATETIME, ACC_date) BETWEEN @p_anneeDebut AND @p_anneeFin
```

For information, `ACC_date` is a string column so I convert it to `DATETIME`. When I call the stored procedure in SQL Server without the parameter but with date like "BETWEEN '2017-01-01' AND '2018-01-01'" it works

Comment: Did you tried this: https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/ You convert the date to the correct format you want.

Comment: What are the values of `dateDebut` and `dateFin` when they're passed into `getAccidents()`?

Comment: @Olivier Belanger Thank's but I have already tested that...

Comment: Can you also please give us the error message you get?

Comment: try using DateTime.Parse(dateDebut)

Comment: @gordon, why they are already of the `DateTime` data type. @Hilai, code looks all right, which database column type is T_ACCIDENT.ACC_Date?

Comment: @squillman it's date like '2018-01-01' in date time format

Comment: then why convert at all? or is it varchar/nvarchar? the correct `convert` formatting hint for odbc canonical yyyy-mm-dd would be 120.

Comment: @dlatikay T_ACCIDENT.ACC_date is a string type so I used the SqlServer function Convert(dateTime,ACC_date)

Comment: What does "it does not work" mean? Why are you storing a date in a string column?

Comment: @AaronBertrand Now the type of acc_date is Date. I haven't got error message but the Where condition is not read by Sql Server. My Where is like that now :...WHERE ACC_date BETWEEN \@p_anneeDebut AND \@p_anneeFin but All my data are displayed in my dataTable

Comment: Are you sure the conversion succeeded? Did you check the values in the table? Did you intercept the statement being sent to SQL Server to make sure your parameters are getting passed correctly?

Comment: But what are the values of BOTH parameters as they get passed into the method in your C# code?  I understand the format, but what are the actual values?

Comment: I would debug this by adding a step in the stored procedure to write the parameter values into a table or something along those lines. You should then be able to work backwards from there to see where the problem is.

Comment: @AaronBertrand to intercept the sql request and put it on sql server I used  cmd.CommandText with the same as storedProcedure, the values return are not great but when I put the request on sql server it works....

Comment: @squillman dateDebut = "2017-01-01" and dateFin = "2018-06-06"

Comment: I also don't know how to interpret "the values return are not great"... ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯